# HFS+ external disk always comes back to read only mode

Tags: mount, hard-drive, hfs+

I use an external HFS+ hard drive on Ubuntu 21.10 and MacOs.

To enable read / write on this disk from Ubuntu:

- On MacOs, I disabled journaling with `sudo diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/my-disk`.
- On Ubuntu, the disk was mounted with [hfsprogs](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/hfsprogs) as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/365270/264961): `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdx# /media/my-user/my-disk`.

Sometimes this works fine, but **very often, I can not write on the disk from Ubuntu: it makes a read-only error**.

---

I tried `sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sd2`, but it does not fix the issue.

One way to fix the issue:

- Plug the disk on MacOs and run `Disk Util` / `First aid`.
- Plug the disk back on Ubuntu and now it can be writed…

Until a few days later, the read-only error comes back.

---

**How can I fix this `read only` error on this external hard drive from Ubuntu (without MacOs)?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also kept this error (Ubuntu 22.04.1), even after disabling journaling in macOS it would after a while (around 2 to 20 days, rebooting daily) mount as read-only again. Extremely annoying!

The solution that seems to work persistently now, is to use `auto` with extra options `nosuid,nodev,x-gvfs-show`.

In `/etc/fstab`, I first had:

```
PARTUUID=xxx /mnt/my_path hfsplus force,rw,auto,nofail 0 0
```

But this seems to work for now:

```
PARTUUID=xxx /mnt/my_path auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,force,rw 0 0
```